# assign propTypes of native child to parent compnent

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I need to pass prop types of a native child component to parent.
e.g:

```js
function MyDivComponent(props) {
    return <div {...props}>{props.children}</div>
}

MyDivComponent.propTypes = div.propTypes // is this possible?
```

Is it possible?

Comment: it is not possible

Answer (score 1):

No, and it also misses the point of `prop-types`.

`propTypes` is a property of a component that we manually define, and on render the library knows to check that property in order to validate the Component's props.

What you're trying to do doesn't make sense, since you want to define which props `MyDivComponent` accepts, without any relation to what it does with said props. A regular `div` doesn't have any `propTypes`, since no-one defined them for it (I guess you could say that its `propTypes` are supported native HTML properties, but as I said, `prop-types` is meant to manually define types and shapes for your props).

Comment: Yes, i mean mapping native element attribute(s) as prop(s) to a component.

Comment: Why would you want to accept native props to your component? In any case, they don't really match. For example, React's `onClick` accepts a function, as to HTML div's `onclick` accepts a string, etc.

Comment: I mean native react element not html element.

Comment: In that case, I don't think its possible.